# 2d barcode scanner inconsistent behavior in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: barcode-scanner, ubuntu-20.04

I am using 2d barcode scanner ( Plug and Play ). This behaves inconsistently when used in any input field or text editor. e.g. Say I scan a barcode while my cursor is blinking in input field of Java swing application, sometimes the input from barcode gets printed in input field really quickly and sometimes I could see characters are getting printed in input field. There is a visible lag of ~second for each character.

This behavior is similar for text editor as well. Not sure how I can check this point. Is there any way to debug this point ?

Comment: That would be the hardware setting of the barcode scanner. The setting barcode should be included in the user's manual, so try changing the setting accordingly. Please contact your scanner vendor for any changes.

Comment: I could not find any such settings for the plug N play barcode. Is there any way we can do it on the Ubuntu OS level ?

Comment: It may be an inexpensive device that does not support such things. In any case, there is almost nothing you can do with the software on the PC side. You may want to buy and try a scanner from a well-known major company.